# Add trusted site to IE local intranet

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, windows-7

I'm trying to make a VBScript that will add exceptions to IE local intranet settings like in the picture. I'm assuming this is possible from what I've read.

[image]

I tried several solutions including the following one, and it feels I'm going nowhere!
The script will be running on Windows 7 Pro machines, if that is of any help.

```
AddTrustedSite "//192.168.0.10"

Function AddTrustedSite(strDomainName)
    Set WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    strRegKey = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\"
    WshShell.RegWrite strRegKey & strDomainName & "\", "", "REG_SZ"
    WshShell.RegWrite strRegKey & strDomainName & "\*", "2", "REG_DWORD"
End Function
```

Comment: Define "going nowhere". What doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Well obviously  i run the script, check IE settings -> local intranet -> sites -> advanced and  `//192.168.0.10` is not getting added.

Comment: Did you check the registry location? Compare it to what you get when you manually add the value.

Comment: With the script it's adding to `/ZoneMap/Domains` , but it looks like i need it in `/ZoneMap/Ranges` because it's a network folder. Now i need to adapt the script for Ranges, but it's a problem because it has different types of values then Domains.

Comment: The values in the `Ranges` subkey have the same types as the ones in your script. It's just the paths and values that are different.

Answer (score 1):

This works for a regular network.
But when using it on a PC under domain, it says wrong username or password. I will post the extra details for domain when i find it.

```
 AddTrustedSite "Range1"

Function AddTrustedSite(strDomainName)
    Set WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    strRegKey = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Ranges\"
    WshShell.RegWrite strRegKey & strDomainName & "\", "", "REG_SZ"
    WshShell.RegWrite strRegKey & strDomainName & "\:Range", "192.168.0.10", "REG_SZ"
    WshShell.RegWrite strRegKey & strDomainName & "\file", "1", "REG_DWORD"
End Function
```